# jquery input on change: zero and empty

Tags: jquery, events

I am using jQuery's `.on('change')` event to detect if the value of an input field has been changed. However, for an initially empty input field, if the user enters 0, the input field will be cleared and the value is considered not changed, as follows:

HTML:

```
<input id=number type=text>
```

jQuery:

```
var $number = $('#number');
$number.on('blur', function() {
  if (this.value == 0) {
    this.value = '';
  }
});

$number.on('change', function() {
  console.log('Changed.');   
});
```

The event `change` is always triggered when the user enters zero. How do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: you could add an `if-else` condition in `.on('change')` event

Comment: actually wht you are trying to achieve u wants to stop the console inside the on change event ?

Comment: Can you explain better what you need? The `blur` event happens after the `change` event. So the former can't prevent the latter from taking place.

Comment: Do you want to prevent entering 0?

Comment: Yes, if user enters 0, I'd like to clear the field. jothi has provided a goog answer below. I should have used only one event

Comment: What do you want to happen if the original value is non-empty and the user changes it to `0`?

Comment: Yes this would be a problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer below for handling that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `focus` event handler to store the original value, and then determine if the value changed for yourself in the `blur` event handler.

```
var $number = $('#number');
$number.on('focus', function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.data('originalValue', $input.val()); 
});
$number.on('blur', function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val().trim() == '0') {
        $input.val('');
    }
    if ($input.val() != $input.data('originalValue')) {
        // Put code to handle a change here.
    }
});
```

This will handle the case where the original value is non-emtpy and the user changes it to `0`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvysnykb/)

---

The problem stems from the fact that the `change` event fires before the `blur` event. You could check in the `change` event handler if the value is `0`, but you won't know if the original value was emtpy or non-empty. If it was emtpy, you don't want to treat it as a change, but if it was non-empty, I am assuming you do want to treat it as a change.

The only solution I can see is to keep track of the original value so you can test for a change yourself.

Comment: This is really what I wanted. Thanks a million, John S.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you want

```
var number = $('#number');

number.on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) 
    {
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
   else
    {
       //do Your stuff here 
     }

  );
```

```js
 var number = $('#number');

    number.on('change', function() {
       
      if ($(this).val() == 0) 
        {
            $(this).val('');
            return false;
        }
       else
        {
          alert("value enter 0");
           //do Your stuff here 
         }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=number type=text>
```

Answer (score 1):

As **currarpickt** suggested, you should add an `if`-check in your `change` handler to ignore the case where the `<input>`'s `value` is `0`, like so:

```
$number.on('change', function() {
  // Return early if the value should be ignored
  if( this.value === '0' ) {
    return;
  }

  // Do your stuff here
});
```

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/snowguy13/Lzw2a4du/3).

Also notice the `blur` event fires *after* the `change` event, so attempts to preemptively modify the input value within the `blur` handler will not be seen by the `change` handler.